ros2: error: argument Call `ros2 <command> -h` for more detailed usage.: invalid choice: 'launch'
sage: ros2 [-h] [--use-python-default-buffering]
Call ros2 <command> -h for more
detailed usage. ...
ros2: error: argument Call ros2 <command> -h for more detailed usage.: invalid choice: 'launch' (choose from 'control', 'daemon', 'extension_points', 'extensions', 'node', 'param', 'pkg', 'run', 'service', 'topic')
Getting the above error on running following command
ros2 launch my_doosan_pkg my_doosan_rviz.launch. py
Can somebody solve this plzz i am stuck here for a while
Here is my launch file code
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import Command
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


def generate_launch_description():
    # robot model to option m1013 or a0912

    robot_model = 'a0912'
    # robot_model = 'm1013'

    xacro_file = get_package_share_directory('my_doosan_pkg') + '/description' + '/xacro/' + robot_model + '.urdf.xacro'

    # Robot State Publisher
    robot_state_publisher = Node(package='robot_state_publisher',
                                 executable='robot_state_publisher',
                                 name='robot_state_publisher',
                                 output='both',
                                 parameters=[{'robot_description': Command(['xacro', ' ', xacro_file])
                                              }])

    # Spawn the robot in Gazebo
    spawn_entity_robot = Node(package='gazebo_ros',
                              executable='spawn_entity.py',
                              arguments=['-entity', 'my_doosan_robot', '-topic', 'robot_description'],
                              output='screen')

    # Start Gazebo with my empty world
    world_file_name = 'my_empty_world.world'
    world = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('my_doosan_pkg'), 'worlds', world_file_name)
    gazebo_node = ExecuteProcess(cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', world, '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'], output='screen')

    return LaunchDescription([robot_state_publisher, spawn_entity_robot, gazebo_node])```
   


Hello, Can you emphasize more about which distro, which os, and how you installed the ROS 2?

I am using ros2 humble on ubuntu 22.04

how you installed the ROS 2?

Using ros 2 official documentation

Please share the exact method, there are multiple official ways to install ROS. In addition, please share how you're setting up your environment and  what'sinstalled in that. And both the full commands you're running and their exact output. To the level that your problem can be reproduced.
